# ParameterizedType and creating a generic dao

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I try this generic code because i don't want to create a dao class for each entity i have in my database because i have 80 ones specially for those who i will excecute just CRUD query. because in most case i need just to persist or make a find by id.

```
public interface GenericDao<T, PK extends Serializable> {

    T create(T t);
    T read(PK id);
    T update(T t);
    void delete(T t);

}
```

the impl of the interface

```
@Component
public class GenericDaoJpaImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> 
                                            implements GenericDao<T, PK> {

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public GenericDaoJpaImpl() {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
             .getGenericSuperclass();
        this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass
             .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Override
    public T create(T t) {
        this.entityManager.persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public T read(PK id) {
        return this.entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T t) {
        return this.entityManager.merge(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T t) {
        t = this.entityManager.merge(t);
        this.entityManager.remove(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Set<T> ts) {
        for( T t : ts){
            t = this.entityManager.merge(t);
            this.entityManager.remove(t);
        }
    }
}
```

the exception

```
Caused by: 
  org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [dao.GenericDaoJpaImpl]: 
  Constructor threw exception; nested exception is 
  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

How to resolve this and what means this `ParameterizedType` and why we have to use it in the constructor ?

and when i comment the constructor it works except for `public T read(PK id)` i got `null pointer exception`

```
    public GenericDaoJpaImpl() {
//      ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
//           .getGenericSuperclass();
//      this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass
//           .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
```

I use it like this :

```
@Autowired
private GenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteAcheteur, Integer> acheteurAlerteDao;
```

i don't want to create a `abstract` class and extend it like this :

```
public class AlerteAcheteurGenericDaoJpaImpl extends GenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteAcheteur, Integer> ... {

}

@Autowired
private AlerteAcheteurGenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteAcheteur, Integer> acheteurAlerteDao;
```

Comment: what is the problem of using it directly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to make it work exactly as you want.

### Part 1. Why it does not work

Note the exact declaration of `GenericDaoJpaImpl` -
`GenericDaoJpaImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, PK>`.

`ClassCastException` is thrown because `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` returns an instance of `Class<java.lang.Object>`, which is `Type` (`java.lang.Class` implements `java.lang.reflect.Type`), but not `ParameterizedType`. In fact, an instance of `Class<java.lang.Object>` is returned by `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` for every class whose direct superclass is `java.lang.Object`. Thus, a constructor like

```
public GenericDaoJpaImpl() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

works for a class declared like `AlerteAcheteurGenericDaoJpaImpl extends GenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteAcheteur, Integer>`. But this is exactly how you do not want to declare your DAOs.

Snippet 1, if ran from your `GenericDaoJpaImpl`, will print `T` and `PK` (both of them will be the instances of `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl`).

*Snippet 1*

```
Type[] genericInterfaces = getClass().getGenericInterfaces();
ParameterizedType genericInterface = (ParameterizedType) genericInterfaces[0];
System.out.println(genericInterface.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
System.out.println(genericInterface.getActualTypeArguments()[1]);
```

*Snippet 2*

```
@Bean(name = "alerteVendeurDao")
public GenericDao<AlerteVendeur, Long> alerteVendeurDao() {
    return new GenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteVendeur, Long>();
}
```

Even if there is something like Snippet 2 in `@Configuration`-annotated class, at runtime it is impossible to know what `GenericDaoJpaImpl` has been parameterized to because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). However, if Snippet 1 was executed from something like `AlerteAcheuteurDao implements GenericDao<AlerteAcheuteur, Long>`, `class somepackage.entity.AlerteAcheteur` and `class java.lang.Long` would be printed (because these parameters are unambiguous and known at compile time).

Finally, the component scanning is not even logically applicable to `GenericDaoJpaImpl`. Beans of [`@Component`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)-annotated classes are "Singleton"-scoped. Besides the fact that only one instance will be created, how would we even know what entity this singleton DAO is supposed to operate on? Nevertheless, the container is still able to instantiate `GenericDaoJpaImpl`, because at runtime the type information is already erased ([type erasure!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)).

Moreover, in relevant cases it is recommended to annotate DAOs with more specific [`@Repository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html), instead of [`@Component`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html).

### Part 2. What could be the best bet?

In your particular case the best bet is to declare an entity class as a constructor parameter. In this way, it is possible to create numerous entity-specific `GenericDaoJpaImpl` instances in Spring configuration by passing appropriate constructor argument to each of them.

*GenericDaoJpaImpl.java*

```
public class GenericDaoJpaImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> 
                                            implements GenericDao<T, PK> {
    private final Class<T> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public GenericDaoJpaImpl(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T create(T t) {
        this.entityManager.persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public T read(PK id) {
        return this.entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T t) {
        return this.entityManager.merge(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T t) {
        t = this.entityManager.merge(t);
        this.entityManager.remove(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Set<T> ts) {
        for( T t : ts){
            t = this.entityManager.merge(t);
            this.entityManager.remove(t);
        }
    }
}
```

*AnnotationContextConfiguration.java*

Please note that it is also possible to do the same in XML via [constructor-based dependency injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("somepackage.service")// scan for services, but not for DAOs!
public class Config {

    @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
    public GenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteAcheteur, Long> alerteAcheteurDao() {
        return new GenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteAcheteur, Long>(AlerteAcheteur.class);
    }

    @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
    public GenericDao<AlerteVendeur, Long> alerteVendeurDao() {
          return new GenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteVendeur, Long>(AlerteVendeur.class);
    }

   // other DAOs

   ...
}
```

*AlerteServiceImpl.java* (how could it look like)

Please note that field names are important, because DAOs are autowired by name. If you do not want to name fields like `alerteAcheteurDao`, you can use [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) with [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html).

```
@Service
public class AlerteServiceImpl implements AlerteService {

    @Autowired
    private GenericDao<AlerteAcheteur, Long> alerteAcheteurDao;

    @Autowired
    private GenericDao<AlerteVendeur, Long> alerteVendeurDao;

    ...
}
```

This is quite an elegant solution. You don't have to spam classes like `AlerteAcheteurGenericDaoJpaImpl extends GenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteAcheteur, Integer>`. Upon adding new entities, you just have to add new instances of `GenericDaoJpaImpl` to Spring configuration.

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: thanks man it was really helpful and  very clear ... i understand now what happened and it will help me a lot in my project ;)

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you.

Comment: can you take a look here @constantine

Answer (score 2):

Your GenericDaoJpaImpl should be abstract. Only concrete descendant type should resolve the generic types T,PK and be defined as Spring beans.

Comment: No i don't want descendant .. i want directly use it like this `@Autowired
 private GenericDaoJpaImpl<AlerteAcheteur, Integer> acheteurAlerteDao;`

Comment: because of type erasure in java you cannot use it the way you do. The JVM doesn't know nothing about <AlerteAcheteur or Integer> at runtime. You have to create a concrete subclass which extends GenericDAOJpaImpl<AlerteAcheteur,Integer>. This way your parameterized type will be available for reflection.....